# how to parse a dictionary inside an array, which is in a dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

In my JSON response i receive a dictionary, which has a array, inside that array is a dictionary with few key-values, to make it simple to understand here is the JSON response:

```
    {
    weather = (
            {
        description = haze;
        icon = 50n;
        id = 721;
        main = Haze;
        }
      );
    }
```

I want to know how can i retrieve the elements description, icon, id and main. Suppose i have a NSString called str, how can i add the value of description to this string. I have tried many different things, but none seem to work. The one i thought should work, but didn't is:

```
str = [[[dir valueForKey:@"weather"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"description"];
```

Can someone let me know how can i access those 4 values. I don't want to create a new array of those values and then retrieve them. Regards.

Comment: print str & show result.

Comment: Have you tried, for "debugging" purposes to actually do each of those calls in a separate line, i.e. get the dictionary, then the first object and then the description. I'm assuming one of those is `nil` it might help you work out where the problem is. By all means then merge it back into one line once you've found the issue. But you are not really creating an array, you are just referencing an existing one

Comment: Seems you are doing right thing. But still have you tried this ?
[[[dir objectForKey:@"weather"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"description"];

Comment: @iOSEnthusiatic - Thanks a lot, that worked !

Comment: @Flexicoder - I actually tried doing that, but xcode displayed an unfamilier (on the web) warning where the NSString property was declared. I had to comment that line and then uncomment it to get rid of the warning, which was very strange so i decided to ask about it here, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NSJSONSerialization` to convert your JSON data to NSObjects.

Then you need to index into your objects based on their structure.

If the structure is fixed, and guaranteed, you can do it with fixed indexes/keys:

```
//data in theJSONDict.

NSArray *outerArray = theJSONDict[@"weather"];
NSDictionary *firstWeatherItem = outerArray[0];
NSString *firstItemDesc = firstWeatherItem[@"description"];
```

You could also do it all in 1 line:

```
firstItemDesc = theJSONDict[@"weather"][0][@"description"];
```

But that is much harder to debug.

If this is JSON data coming from a server you need to code more defensively than above, and write code that tries to fetch keys from dictionaries, tests for nil, and either loops through the array(s) using the count of objects, or tests the length of the array before blindly indexing into it. Otherwise you'll likely crash if your input data's format doesn't match your assumptions.

(BTW, do not use `valueForKey` for this. That is `KVO` code, and while it *usually* works, it is not the same as using NSArray and NSDictionary methods to fetch the data, and sometimes does not work correctly.)

Comment: My mentor did point out the same thing, what if i try to set a value but it is not included in the response by the server, i tried that and it gets set to null, so do i still need to check if a value is sent by the server or not ?

Comment: You asked "do i still need to check if a value is sent by the server or not?". Good programming practice is to validate any data that is sent to you from an outside source. So yes.